# How to include exceptional handling mechanism in CXF Restful WebServices using JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

I have followed this link for building my CXF Restful WebServices [URL](http://www.lessonslab.com/building-restful-webservices-using-apache-cxf/150/) .
I'm trying to handle exceptions in these webservices.

Can anyone please suggest me some links about how to include exceptional handling mechanism in my webservices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are doing following thing:

```
@Component
public class ThrowableInterceptor
  implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>
{
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( ThrowableInterceptor.class );

  @Override
  public Response toResponse( Throwable exception )
  {
   logger.error(
      "Exception with caught", exception );
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(
      ServiceErrorCodes.GENERAL_ERROR.getErrorCode(), "unknown error" );
    return Response.status( Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR )
      .type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE )
      .entity( errorResponse )
      .build();
  }
}
```

As you can see there is ExceptionMapper and if some Throwable will be thrown it will go to this interceptor and will be wrapped to custom ErrorResponse. You can use this approach and customize any exception handling i.e. validationException, dataAccessException e.t.c